# How to STOP caches_page from setting page in cache permanently? -- Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, ruby-on-rails-3.1, http-headers

I want to make sure that if the file changes (if cache files are deleted for example), the user's browser shouldn't load the cached version.

Here is the issue I found. **Here are the headers when I DON'T use `caches_page`:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK => 
ETag => "4ff902bc57e1892d7a963e43bf56dcc8"
X-UA-Compatible => IE=Edge,chrome=1
Cache-Control => max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Runtime => 2.710376
X-Rack-Cache => miss
Set-Cookie => _Myapp_session=.....; path=/; HttpOnly
Status => 200
```

**And here are the headers when I do use it:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK => 
ETag => "80003-1ad93-4b44a71a41180"
Last-Modified => Sat, 17 Dec 2011 14:22:14 GMT
Accept-Ranges => bytes
```

I've removed the common lines for easy comparison.

**Are there any issues with these differing headers?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any rails way to do this so put in "Header set" directives in apache.conf